# Finding unique documents in an index in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am having duplicates entries in my index and I want to find out only unique documents in the index . TopHits aggregation solves this problem but my other requirement is to support sorting on the results (across buckets). Hence I cant use top hits aggregation.
Other options I can think of is to write a plugin or use painless script.
Need help to solve this.It would be great if you can redirect me to some examples.

Comment: What makes an entry duplicate?

Comment: An example of what kind of documents you have would help. The completion suggester (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html#querying) has an option to `skip_duplicates`, which might be helpful if you're dealing with descriptions / comments.  I guess it also cannot do sorting? But it should search across multiple shards.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent One my flink  job inserts events into elastic search and I was not able to avoid duplicates there because of our event structure. So only way for me is to remove duplicates while reading from elastic search. Also as I mentioned earlier, I want to have sorting ability also. I can do aggregation but it sorts only documents inside a bucket.

Comment: @Tessmore .   {
 "id" : "id1",
 "userName" : "sumit",
 "location" : "bangalore",
 "operation" : "read",
 "entity" : "file1"
}
Duplicate event :
{
 "id" : "id1",
 "userName" : "sumit",
 "location" : "bangalore",
 "operation" : "read",
 "entity" : "file1"
}

Comment: @SumitNekar the best thing I can think of is creating determinate IDs based on the doc contents. This will prevent duplicates from ever being created.

Answer (score 1):

`Top hits` aggregation find the value from the complete result set while If you use `cardinality` it gives only filtered result set.
You can use `cardinality` aggregation like below:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "UNIQUE_COUNT" : {
            "cardinality" : {
                "field" : "your_field"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This aggregation comes with some responsibility, You can find the below ElasticSearch documentation to understand it better.
Link: [Cardinality Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html)

For sorting, you can refer the below example, where you can pass your aggregation in order of `terms` for which your bucket get created:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "AGG_NAME": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "you_field",
                "size": 10,
                "order": {
                    "UNIQUE_COUNT.doc_count": "asc"
                },
                "min_doc_count": 1
            },
            "aggs": {
                "UNIQUE_COUNT": {
                    "cardinality": {
                        "field": "your_field"
                    }
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This can give us unique counts. My requirement is  :  I pass a search query expression and a sort param . The result should not have duplicates. I actually want use the resulted documents and send them as a response to client. So Cardinality Aggregation gives me only unique count not unique documents.